# Angularjs 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' on multiple subdomain request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel

I would like to check, I know that JavaScript code is limited by the same-origin policy so which means that if i try to made a request to any foreign origin i will be caught by 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error, which is fine as long as i can define it in the header. My problem is, I am not sure if my way of doing is correct because I do not see any value is being passed to the header upon request. Here is my Angular code: (Noted that I am using $resource to handle all the requests)

```
var SomeApp = angular.module('SomeApp',['ngResource','ngSanitize'])
SomeApp.factory('SomeAppService', ['$resource', function($resource){

    return {          
       firstActions : $resource(svrid('acns') + '/action/:payload',{payload:'@payload'},
                {
                    'remove': {method:'DELETE',isArray:true, cache:false},
                    'save' : {method:'POST', isArray:true, cache:false, headers:{'X-CSRF-TOKEN': CSRF_TOKEN, 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}},
                    'query' : {method:'GET', isArray:true,cache:false},
                }, {cache:false}        
        ),

        //some more other functions
    };

 }]);
```

so as you can see i have already include `headers:{'X-CSRF-TOKEN': CSRF_TOKEN, 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}` in one of the post method but upon executing the action, browser console still prompt me with this error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://acns.example.com:8000/action/rIqj7RVUdeFVwkp36uxjCUzlYAXaTKwBeyJjdCMxZjk3OWU1NGQwYzRjODFlYWRjNDFkYzAyMGE1ZCIsInMiOiJmMTU4MDZjOWM1YjFlNWFjIn0=.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://www.example.com:8000' is therefore not
>   allowed access.

What am I missing in this scenario? In addition I would also like to ask if is it possible to make the header apply to the entire `firstAction` functions? As I have read in [AngularJS documentation on $http](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/docs/api/ng/service/$http) it applies to the particular action itself. I am using AngularJS 1.3.15

Please enlighten me with any possible solutions. Thank you

Update 1 : I have installed a module by [barryvdh](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors), partially fixed the issue but not 100% complete due to some [errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31184740/angularjs-access-control-allow-origin-using-laravel-cors) found in this new topic. Hope someone can close this topic.

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a **response** header that must be set by the **server**, not the client. Have a good read of this ~ http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Comment: What do you use in your backend ?

Comment: For your second question, you can either add headers to each action in your `$resource` or add a request interceptor to the `$http` defaults ~ https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors

Comment: @NelsonPatricioJimenez backend uses php laravel 5 framework nginx server... Will that affect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access-Control-Allow-Origin is a response header. you can understand this reading about [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). (Specified reading the Simple example)

In my case in rails I can manage this with this gem [rack-cors](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors), in laravel I found this package for laravel Cors https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors

Comment: i have tried your method when when i check on the header section nothing is being returned from the response headers

Comment: I just update the post, Can you try this package ? https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors, If you have a question ask me. :D

Comment: alright mate... I will try it and will come back to you if I face any problem... Thanks for helping me out mate...

Comment: i manage to install the module but my current problem is that my preflight OPTIONS do not return me with any of the supposed headers. Pls see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31184740/angularjs-access-control-allow-origin-using-laravel-cors)

Comment: Can you share the full file where you use CORS package ?

Comment: sure. What do you mean by the full file?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are already doing this, but there are a few ways to set the response header in Laravel (which I assume you are using). I'm also using Angularjs in one of my apps and I ended up doing this to fix a similar problem.

In the "before" event in my filters.php, I added this:

```
App::before(function($request)
{
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Accept, X-Request-With, Token');

// .....

});
```

Hope it helps...