# Angularjs 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' using Laravel CORS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel, laravel-5

I have just installed Laravel CORS by [barryvdh](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors), the module works fine to my knowledge but i seem to be still facing the Access-Control-Allow-Origin error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://acns.example.com:8000/status/d6uIlvwwi8PrvQe4kQfufyZ0LlqQqJyGeyJjdC…I4OTYzMTJlYzYyMmMxOTVkNWI5YjNjYzM1MTczNyIsInMiOiI2ZDcwZDg5N2FkOTQxZDFkIn0=.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://www.example.com:8000' is therefore not
>   allowed access.

below is my angular code to execute the function:

```
var SomeApp = angular.module('SomeApp',['ngResource','ngSanitize'])
SomeApp.factory('SomeAppService', ['$resource', function($resource){

    return {          
       firstActions : $resource(svrid('acns') + '/action/:payload',{payload:'@payload'},
                {
                    'remove': {method:'DELETE',isArray:true, cache:false},
                    'save' : {method:'POST', isArray:true, cache:false},
                    'query' : {method:'GET', isArray:true,cache:false},
                }, {cache:false}        
        ),

        //some more other functions
    };

 }]);
```

While further diving into the code, i realize that the supposingly appended headers are not being included in the xhr request (refer image below)

[image: error]

What am I missing here?

**Update 1:** I slightly narrow down the problem most probably related to [barryvdh's laravel-cors](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors) that uses [asm89's stack-cors](https://github.com/asm89/stack-cors) where by the config\cors.php is not properly passed to asm89. Not very confident with the problem but i did some manual override which causes `OPTIONS` to work when i manually pass the array in `config\cors.php` to asm89 but then on the other hand causes other methods to fail.

**Update 2:** i tried manually alter a section under `Asm89\Stack\CorsService` give it a default value like such:

```
private function normalizeOptions(array $options = array())
    {
            $options += array(
            'allowedOrigins' => array('*'),
            'supportsCredentials' => true,
            'allowedHeaders' => array('*'),
            'exposedHeaders' => array('*'),
            'allowedMethods' => array('*'),
            'maxAge' => 0,
        );
        // Some other codes
        // normalize array('*') to true

        return $options;
    }
```

and comment out one small section

```
public function handlePreflightRequest(Request $request)
{
    /*if (true !== $check = $this->checkPreflightRequestConditions($request)) {
    return $check;
    }*/

    return $this->buildPreflightCheckResponse($request);
}
```

It works perfectly for preflight `OPTIONS` and `GET` method but `POST` and `DELETE` method will prompt me with an error

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://www.example.com:8000' is therefore not
>   allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

After the preflight `OPTIONS` request

Comment: If I recall correctly, the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header should be present on your response, so you might have to update the server giving the response.

Comment: @Shilly what or how do you do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the CORS response headers in the server side.

Comment: what or how do you do that?

Comment: Please refer this link. http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/how-to-add-cors-support-on-the-server-side-in-java-with-jersey/

Comment: The purpose of the library the OP is trying to include is supposed to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue, where all cross-domain AJAX requests would work, expect for POST requests.  The POST responses would be missing the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header, but GET and DELETE requests functioned as expected.

It turned out that I had disabled suppression of deprecated warning in php.ini, and by using

```
$data = Input::json()->all();
```

in my controller, PHP was throwing a

```
 PHP Deprecated:  Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To avoid this warning set 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini and use the php://input stream instead. in Unknown on line 0
```

warning, followed by a

```
PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent
```

warning.

**This meant that my custom headers were never sent.  I fixed the problem by simply suppressing the deprecated warnings in php.ini.**

The deprecated problem I will have to deal with in the future, but for now it's a functioning workaround to getting POST data from JSON requests in laravel.